# Download multiple files in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can anyone tell me how to download the multiple files via apex?
I have a visualforce page which contains download button. Once I click this    button then it will download all the files in my attachement object.
For that how can i implement.

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Answer (score 2):

You can create page with links to your attachments or add multiple attachments in zip archive.

Comment: can you give me the sample code for how to add multiple attachments in zip

Comment: The easiest way in this case is create zip on client side.
Following link can be useful http://www.valnavjo.com/blog/compressing-files-in-salesforce/

Comment: Can you tell me some other method to implement the above usecase